# Align 2 overlapping photos of a page of text

Tags: opencv, text, feature-extraction

I've got 2 images of text where the right side of the first image overlaps with the left side of the second (2 partial photos of the same page of text taken from left to right).
I'd like to stitch the images and I'm trying an approach with feature matching.
I've tried the example with the ORB feature search + brute force feature matching from the OpenCV site http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher

It's completely off (doesn't find any correct matches, all false positives) in my case at least with the default parameters of the feature search. It looks logical that it would have a hard time in case of text if it uses corners.

How do I match this kind of images with text more reliably with feature matching? Should I specify some different non-default parameters for the ORB search algorithm? use a different algorithm with different parameters?

If not feature matching what other approach with Open CV can I use for this alignment?

```
Mat p1 = new Mat("part1.jpg", LoadMode.GrayScale);
Mat p2 = new Mat("part2.jpg", LoadMode.GrayScale);

var orb = new ORB();

Mat ds1;
var kp1 = DetectAndCompute(orb, p1, out ds1);

Mat ds2;
var kp2 = DetectAndCompute(orb, p2, out ds2);

var bfMatcher = new BFMatcher(NormType.Hamming, crossCheck: true);
var matches = bfMatcher.Match(ds1, ds1);

var tenBestMatches = matches.OrderBy(x => x.Distance).Take(10);

var res = new Mat();
Cv2.DrawMatches(p1, kp1, p2, kp2, tenBestMatches, res, flags: DrawMatchesFlags.DrawRichKeypoints);


using (new Window("result", WindowMode.ExpandedGui, res))
{
    Cv2.WaitKey();
}
```

---

```
private static KeyPoint[] DetectAndCompute(ORB orb, Mat p1, out Mat ds1)
{
    var kp1 = orb.Detect(p1);
    ds1 = new Mat();
    orb.Compute(p1, ref kp1, ds1);
    return kp1;
}
```

[image: image description]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. About ORB approach what comes to my mind it can lead to many false positives because of the subject (printed letters on a paper) we are trying to process. Firstly, we have a complexity of possible features to detect - various characters combined together, relatively small in compare to feature size. Increasing size of the features rapidly increase possible number of them.  Secondly, you can have detected the same letters on the beginning of some word belonging to different words, so you cannot just rely separately on each detected match, rather than information should be combined together. Generally I would try to tweak an orb detector patch size ([C++ case](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html#orb)) trying to balance its size. And try SIFT or SURF, maybe they will have better results in your case.

Another approach, definitely brute force. Based on the example you've provided, it should be possible to detect separate words (thresholding -> blob detection). So let's assume we have detected blobs with the words. Lets say we have some set A and B, detected words from left and right images respectively. Then we should find the maximum of function overlap() on the every pair of words in A x B:

> pos = arg_max{(a,b) in A x B: overlap(a,b)}

And an overlap function would be any function that takes two images anc computes its similarity. You can use there e.g. histogram comparison, sum of absolute differences ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching#Template-based_matching_and_convolution)) or any template matching algorithm that would balance accuracy and performance. When comparing two words images, it should be invariant to translation, scaling and rotation and that will also increase a complexity.

Generally the question is not easy and therefore research interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried varying the patch size, it doesn't work. Trying the image similarity approach now. Tried phaseCorellate but it gives a lot of false positives. Will look for and try other methods.